# Stringstream incompletely filled

Tags: c++, sstream

Why does this code fragment:

```
 if (iErr) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    string serror("error");
    ss << "lua error code " << iErr << ": " << lua_tostring(lua, -1);
    ss >> serror;

    Log *log= StandardLog::getInstance();
    log->logError("Lua error following in next line");
    log->logError(serror);

    //lua_pop(lua, 1);/* pop error message from the stack */
    return 1;
 }
```

just print:

```
Lua error following in next line
lua
```

instead of

```
Lua error following in next line
lua error code 3: lua/generator/generator_example_nodenavigator.lua:10: attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)
```

The Logger lines look like this:

```
void Logger::log(char message[]){
    string smessage(message);
    log(smessage);
}

void Logger::log(string smessage){
    ...
}
```

but it appears the logger is not at fault, since i get the same output using cerr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input operator `>>` extracts only until the next whitespace. Either use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or the [`stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) function to get the string.

My recommendation is to change to [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and use [`std::ostringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str):

```
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << "lua error code " << iErr << ": " << lua_tostring(lua, -1);

Log *log= StandardLog::getInstance();
log->logError("Lua error following in next line");
log->logError(oss.str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The extraction operator you're using reads a *space-delimited* string from the input stream. So, it stops when it hits the first space in our input.

Just replace

```
log->logError(serror);
```

with

```
log->logError(ss.str());
```

(and you don't need `serror` at all).